# Sharing types between frontend and backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, postgresql, nestjs

I want to share types between frontend and backend. Fronted is created with react and typescript, backend is created with Nest.js and PostgreSQL. Both projects are in separated repo, so monorepo is not an option. I thought about GraphQL, or private packages with types, but it will require keeping the same versions of packages on the front and backend. Do you have any ideas how to share types? I also have swagger but sometimes types are incorrect or they are missing, so i would like to have more safety solution.

Comment: have a look at bit.dev, it is a nice platform to achieve that

Comment: As Jorge said, bit.div seems good to evaluation. I have searched for that subject when I saw your question and I saw bit.div. Maybe you can want to look [this article](https://bit.dev/blog/sharing-types-between-your-frontend-and-backend-applications-l5qih48g)